# FIFO channel reading incorrect

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, fifo

I have 2 unrelated processes. The first creates a FIFO channel and writes data to it.

*testcomp:*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f1;
    char *send_buf = "Hello";
    char recv_buf[128] = {0};

    if (mkfifo("mk.fifo", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
        error(0, errno, "mkfifo() error");

    f1 = open("mk.fifo", O_RDWR);
    perror("Opening ");

    printf("Sending string '%s'...\n", send_buf);
    write(f1, send_buf, strlen(send_buf));
    perror("Writing ");

    close(f1);
    return 0;
}
```

The second process should read data from a previously created channel.

*test2comp:*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f2;
    char recv_buf[128] = {0};

    f2 = open("mk.fifo", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
    perror("Opening ");

    read(f2, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf));
    perror("Reading ");

    printf("Received string '%s'\n", recv_buf);

    close(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the read **data is empty**. What could be the reason?

Console output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A FIFO is just a named pipe.

It has to be open at both ends *at the same time* for communication to occur. For example, your local [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) should say something like

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special
>          file that is opened by at least one process.  The FIFO must be opened
>          on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed.
>          Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

What you did is:

1. create a FIFO inode
2. open it for writing, implicitly creating a pipe associated with that inode
3. write something into the pipe buffer even though nothing is reading from it yet
4. close it again, destroying the pipe
5. open a new pipe for reading, associated with the same (currently un-used) inode
6. there's nothing in there, because it's a new pipe

Normally I would expect the writer to block when opening the fifo, until a reader is present - I'm not sure why this didn't happen. You explicitly disabled this behaviour for the reader though by setting it to non-blocking.

Comment: Great summary. Removing some of the FIFO flags resulted in a working example for me.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me the correct algorithm for my example?

Comment: The simplest thing is probably to start the reader first, without the non-blocking flag. Once it is running and blocked (waiting), you can start the writer in a different shell.

Comment: So I write down first, and only then read. Why should I read where there is nothing?

Comment: ITS TRUUUUUUUUEEEEEE

Comment: @Useless Honestly, I tried to do without a non-blocking flag, but then it did not help. But now everything is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: For those who are interested - I changed from O_RDWR to O_WRONLY. "f1 = open("mk.fifo", O_WRONLY);" The O_WRONLY flag locks until a read command is called.